# How to use proxy server while authenticate using LDAP in Spring Boot?

Tags: ldap, spring-ldap, ldap-query, spring-security-ldap

How to set proxy server ip in **LdapContextSource** while authenticated using **LdapTemplate.authenticate()**

Actually for security purposes we don't have direct access to AD server. So how to set proxy IP for this in spring boot?

```
LdapContextSource contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
contextSource.setUrl("ldap://corp.opustech.net:389");
contextSource.setBase("dc=corp,dc=opustech,dc=net");
contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();

LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
filter.and(new EqualsFilter("uid", "rahul.i"));
boolean isAuthenticated = ldapTemplate.authenticate("", filter.toString(), "opustech@23");
```

Comment: Is this client-side code? or server-side code? If the latter, it should certainly have access to the AD.

Comment: This is client side code.